# Where is the index.html on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) Apache setup?

Tags: macos

I've started up Apache on my Mac and get the "It works!" message, but I have no idea where that file is.

I've checked the httpd.conf file and the location listed is:

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

Yet, when I go to the /Library/WebServer/Documents folder, it is empty!

This one is driving me crazy, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you change the directory, does it stop displaying the page, if it doesn't then you have the wrong httpd.conf file

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Server Application on `/Applications/Server.app`.

There is a Websites Service in the left pane. Click to configure on the right panel.